# redirect page(https) to external URL(http) with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect https://www.siteone.com/testpage-es.html to http://newsite.com

When I'm testing my code in a htaccess tester (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) it shows the following result.
"The new URL is http://newsite.com:443/"

My code is snippet as follows.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.siteone.com$ [NC]
 
RewriteRule ^testpage-es.html$ http://newsite.com [L,R=301,NC]

Could anyone please help me to get rid of ":443/" part?

Answer (score 1):

Add port to your rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?siteone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^testpage-es\.html$ http://newsite.com:443 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But port 443 is default for SSL/HTTPS so rule should look (with https:// not port number)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?siteone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^testpage-es\.html$ https://newsite.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: My code worked properly in the live environment. I have done the same as you mentioned.
The above problem only occurred when I'm checking the code with htaccess tester and it was working properly with the live site.
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to find the answer. This is only a problem related to the htaccess checker with https websites. The code I mentioned above worked properly in the live environment. (I was hesitant to check it with the live web site without being 100% sure. However, it works well in the live environment.)